# Google map geocode function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have make a function to validate latitude and longitude and that returns true and false based on latlong

```
function valitdateLatLong(latitude, longitude) {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

how should i call this function?
i have used

```
if(valitdateLatLong($("#Latitude").val(), $("#Longitude").val())){
    // logic
}
else{
   // logic
}
```

but it is not working fine.
Please help me.

Comment: What is an invalid latitude/longitude? Surely any latitude in [-90, +90] and any longitude in [-180, +180] (degrees for both) is *valid*? - - - Also, in what way is it "*not working fine*"?

Comment: this function will return true if it will find any address for that point.So when there is a latlong that point to any ocean will not create any address.

Comment: what is the issue ? your code is perfect for validation.

Comment: it  returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a promise.

`geocoder.geocode`, will call the remote server and it takes time to execute the task. Since it takes a lot of time (a few seconds), the result comes back as a callback (AsyncTask).

You can either put you logic inside the AsyncTask, or use a promise.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/18/geolocation-geocoding-and-jquery-promises.aspx